# To remove duplicate elements from an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, duplicates, element

I have a data set

```
10-101570715-101609901-hsa-mir-3158-1   10-101600739-101609661-ENSG00000166171  10-101588288-101609668-ENSG00000166171  10-101588325-101609447-ENSG00000166171  10-101594702-101609439-ENSG00000166171  10-101570560-101596651-ENSG00000166171  

10-103389007-103396515-hsa-mir-1307 10-103389041-103396023-ENSG00000173915  10-103389050-103396074-ENSG00000173915  10-103389050-103396441-ENSG00000173915  10-103389050-103396466-ENSG00000173915  10-103389050-103396466-ENSG00000173915
```

Except for the first element in each line, I have multiple values, which are redundant and I want to remove the redundant values. I have written a code but I don't feel its working fine.

```
open (fh, "file1");
while ($line=<fh>)
{
chomp ($line);
@array=$line;
my @unique = ();
my %Seen   = ();
foreach my $elem ( @array )
    {
    next if $Seen{ $elem }++;
    push @unique, $elem;
    }
print @unique;
}
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%Seen;` Aren't you looking for duplicates using full lines?

Comment: no, not duplicate using full lines, only searching for elements, that are duplicated within a line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a hash is for duplicate detection :

```
my %seen;
my @removeduplicate = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @array;
```

For me below code is working fine :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
open my $fh, "<", 'file.txt' or die "couldn't open : $!";
while ( my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split (' ', $line);
    my @removeduplicate = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @array;
    print "@removeduplicate\n";
}
```

Comment: the redundant values are still there

Comment: @MANAUWERRAZA : have a look at my edited answer. always use `use warnings` and `use strict` and three arguments for file operation.

Comment: thank you, the code written earlier worked too, it was on my sheer part of negligence..

Comment: If this helped you, you can select this as an aswer.